# What's the best way to get adjacent characters in JavaScript array of strings?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

Let's say I have this:

`var arr = [ "Exploring the zoo, we saw every kangaroo jump and quite a few carried babies.", "The wizard quickly jinxed the gnomes before they vaporized.", "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog."];`

I'm trying to figure out a way for when I input "jinxed", I'm also getting "wizard quickly" and "gnomes before". Not necessarly the whole words, I only want to get few characters next and previous to the input. I've been hitting walls around this, so I appreciate any suggestions and tips.

Thanks!

Comment: So if the input is "jinxed" you want to get back: {charBefore:" ", charAfter:" "}? Those spaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function scan(arr, w) {

    // This function is a first attempt to solve your specific problem.
    // It just looks for the first occurence of w, the word you are looking for
    // It does not cover edge or specific cases, neither is optimized.
    // With more specifications, it can be generalized.
    // Hope it can help.

    var 
        // utils
        regWord = /\w+/g,
        wordsBefore, wordsAfter,
        matchWord,
        found = false;

    // loop through your array
    arr.forEach(function(item) {

    if (found) {
      // if we have already found the word, skip the iteration
      return false;
    }

    // clear the arrays of words before and after
    wordsBefore = []; 
    wordsAfter = [];

    // strip the words from the array item
    // every match is an iterable object containing the word, its index, and the item string
    while (match = regWord.exec(item)) {

      // get the matched word 
      matchWord = match[0].toLowerCase();

      // if we have found the word we are looking for
      if (matchWord === w.toLowerCase()) {

        // flag it
        found = true;

      } else {
        // it is not a match, but a word that could be returned in the array before or after

        if (!found) {
          // if we have not found the word yet

          // populate the array of words before
          wordsBefore.push(matchWord);

        } else {
          // otherwise, if we are here, it means that we are in a sentence containing
          // the word we are looking for, and we have already found it

          // populate the array of words after
          wordsAfter.push(matchWord);

        }

      }

    }

  });


  // return an object containing
  return {
    // the words before
    wordsBefore: wordsBefore,
    // the words after
    wordsAfter: wordsAfter 
  } 

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `split` to get what's before and what's after `jinxed`, and then use `substr` to get the last or first characters in each part:

```
var a = "The wizard quickly jinxed the gnomes before they vaporized";
var s = a.split('jinxed');

s == [ 'The wizard quickly ',' the gnomes before they vaporized' ]

s[0].substr(-10,10) == 'd quickly '
s[1].substr(0,10) == ' the gnome'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use RegEx match:

```js
function search(s,q, msg) {
  // match the characters before and after
  var m = s.match(new RegExp("(.|^)" + q + "(.|$)"));
console.log(m);
  // if there was a match at all, then drop the 1st (which is the whole match: " jinxed ")
  if (m) {
    if(m.length>1) {m = m.splice(1)}
    // m[0] in the character before, m[1] is the one after
    alert(msg + " '" + m[0] + "', '" + m[1] + "'");
  } else {
    alert(msg + " not found");
  }
}

search("The wizard quickly jinxed the gnomes before they vaporized.","jinxed", "in the middle");
search("jinxed the gnomes before they vaporized.","jinxed", "in the beginning");
search("The wizard quickly jinxed","jinxed","in the end");
search("jinxed","jinxed","full");
search("The wizard quickly","jinxed","not in string");
```

Note that this works also when the string you are searching is at the beginning or the end of the line.